# Converting Value from VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got the following problem in my query

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '190,191,192' to data type int.

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM SGI_User
JOIN SGI_Agency_User
ON SGI_User.User_Id = SGI_Agency_User.User_Id
WHERE SGI_Agency_User.Agency_Id IN
(select STUFF(
                (select CAST(',' as varchar(max)), cast(agency_id as int)
                from sgi_agency
                where filial_de_int_matriz = 192 or 
                (Agency_Id = 192 and Filial_De_int_matriz = 0)
                for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''))
and SGI_User.Deleted = 0
```

These 3 values `190,191,192` came from this query

```
select STUFF(
        (select CAST(',' as varchar(max)), cast(agency_id as int)
        from sgi_agency
        where filial_de_int_matriz = 192 or 
        (Agency_Id = 192 and Filial_De_int_matriz = 0)
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

that returns a `varchar` but my `SGI_Agency_User.Agency_Id` field is `INT` I've tried some `CAST` but without success. How can I do this query ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to split the string into individual values so that they an be converted into ints?

Comment: this is the question, I can put a `IN` statement in my query to search for `INT` value, but how can I convert my subquery to a group of `INT` numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you think you need to convert these `INT` values to a string in the first place...

Can't you just simply use:

```
WHERE SGI_Agency_User.Agency_Id IN
                (SELECT agency_id
                 FROM sgi_agency
                 WHERE filial_de_int_matriz = 192 
                    OR (Agency_Id = 192 AND Filial_De_int_matriz = 0)
                )
```

and skip all the converting back and forth altogether? This subquery is going to return a list of integer values, which can be used by the `IN` operation - no problem, no need for any conversions whatsoever ...